# Matplotlib: How to create multiple bar charts side by side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart

I'm looking to re-create the attached figure using MatplotLib. The content will be different (is arbitrary), but the features of the plot should all be present. These I'm new to Matplotlib and had a look at the tutorials. I found one on bar charts and one on sharing y-axis, but so far I have been unsuccessful and am a bit overwhelmed. I would really appreciate if there were some pros around it who could provide some sample code or guide me in the right direction. My main difficulties are with creating a bar chart with non-touching columns, getting the axis nice and clean as in the picture and aligning the resulting bar charts next to each other.

Many thanks, 
Max

[image: The plot I'm trying to create:]

Comment: There is [♠an example on the matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) about grouped bar charts. You should have a look at it, implement it and if you then have a problem, ask specifically about it. As it stands this question is really too broad to be answered.

Comment: Okay, I'm working with that at the moment. I'm trying to get as far as possible with it, will post it later and then maybe someone can help out with the specific issues I'm facing.